# Как сделать int для каждого элемента списка во вложенных списках?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть какой-то двумерный список:

a = [['6', '3', '1'], ['5', '4', '-8'], ['-7', '3', '6']]

как каждый его элемент преобразовать в целочисленное?:

a = [[6, 3, 1], [5, 4, -8], [-7, 3, 6]]

Comment: Пройтись циклом по списку а, внутри которого пройтись циклом по каждому вложенному списку, меняя тип элементов внутри. А в чем затык с написанием кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам и не нужно использовать map, если можно использовать простую генерацию списков:

```
a = [['6', '3', '1'], ['5', '4', '-8'], ['-7', '3', '6']]
a = [[int(i) for i in j] for j in a]
print(a)
```

> [[6, 3, 1], [5, 4, -8], [-7, 3, 6]]

Comment: как раз то, что я пытался реализовать.
Только я писал: a = [[int(i) for j in range(a)] for i in range(a)] и у меня вылетала ошибка
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [['6', '3', '1'], ['5', '4', '-8'], ['-7', '3', '6']]

res = [list(map(int, i)) for i in a]
print(res)
```

Comment: столкнулся с этой проблемой при решении задачи из курса.
но map мы не разбирали еще, поэтому я не могу его использовать=\
но ваш вариант работает как надо, спасибо)